# It should be possible to ask questions about Martial arts texts

Tags: discussion

One guy [asked a question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/1850/70) about a book written by the founder of Aikido, and the question was closed. Unsurprisingly, that question had been closed on a language-based stackexchange... And then it was closed here, too.

Clarification on martial texts should be a part of the allowed questions here. That's my stance.

Answer (score 1):

I discussed it with Matt, and while it is unlikely to attract an answer he agreed that it could be reopened. Thanks Matt :)